# convert negative value to zero in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

How to convert negative values to zero in a calculated column?
we have inner join of multiple tables where a column is a calculated column taken from tables,i need to convert negative values present in the column to zero, how can i do?
what was tried..
i tried with 'case' condition but its not working.

part of code where i intend to change is similar to like this

```
(isnull((select isnull(sum(AVAILPHYSICAL),0) from ax.inventsum 
  where ITEMID = ax.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID ))-
  (select isnull(sum(QTY*-1),0) from ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS RTST  inner join ax.RETAILTRANSACTIONTABLE RTT
    on RTT.TRANSACTIONID = RTST.TRANSACTIONID
    where ITEMID=ax.INVENTTABLE.ITEMID and (RTT.ENTRYSTATUS = 0 OR RTT.ENTRYSTATUS = 2) and
    (RTST.TRANSACTIONSTATUS = 0 or 
     RTST.TRANSACTIONSTATUS = 2 ) and 
     As Quantity,
```

Comment: `case when f < 0 then 0 else f end` ? or for integers `(abs(f)+f)/2` makes `f == 0` for `f < 0`

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Like [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: `Foo * ( ( Sign( Foo ) + 1 ) / 2 )` will work for SQL Server.

Comment: @AlexK. Some potential for overflow there. Otherwise that's nicely concise.

Comment: @AlexK. case option works fine, but here f is computed column from joins which has around 11k records which is affecting the performance badly,any suggestion on improving performance?